# Sidebar not appearing

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, sidebar

Hi my sidebar is not appearing when I click on the toggle button. I see it moving to the side but the sidebar is blank/transparent. 
I think it has something to do with my js file. 
Could someone help me out I am fairly new to coding and this community. 
Thanks in advance !!

```js
/* Set the width of the sidebar to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px */
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mysidebar").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}


/* Set the width of the sidebar to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0 */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mysidebar").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
```

```html
<body>

    <section id="mysidebar">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chapter 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chapter 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chapter 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chapter 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chapter 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</button>
            <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>        
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="C:\Users\quinc\Documents\Developer\Project 2.0\js\members.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

has something to do with my js script. I can't figure out the problem.

Could someone help me out, I am new to coding and it's my first project I am working on. 
I have placed my HTML, CSS and JS code down below.

Thank you

Comment: "The sidebar is blank/transparent" - The sidebar contains a `ul`, did you mean to add more HTML?

Comment: Provide your css which makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the main section `mysidebar`. Your `mysidebar` section is set to `width: 0` when you click `closeNav` function.

Instead that you need to access `sidebar` div and also just setting `width:0` won't work because `sidebar` div contains `ul` element which takes some width and text inside `ul li a` also takes some width. So you can use css `display` property

Change your `openNav` and `closeNav` function.

```
function openNav() {
    var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
    sidebar.style.width = "250px";
    sidebar.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}


/* Set the width of the sidebar to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0 */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
```

change your html. Add `id` to sidebar

```
<div id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chapter 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chapter 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chapter 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chapter 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chapter 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hey SR Thapa, thank you for your input I have figured it out with your HTML code by removing the section and placing mysidebar id into the div and add sidebar as a class. I kept my JS code. Thank you very much

Comment: It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("mysidebar").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  }
```

```html
<section id="mysidebar">
  <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Chapter 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Chapter 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Chapter 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Chapter 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Chapter 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="main">
    <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</button>
    <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>        
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi Partho63 thank you for your input but i have figured it out with a previous comment.